# How to prevent caching of spritesheet image, referenced in json?

Tags: javascript, html, json, caching

I'm using PIXIJS engine and TexturePacker.
To prevent file caching I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var PIXIJS_VERSION = "4.3.5";
    var VERSION = "0.0.7b";
    document.write('\<script src="lib/pixi.min.js?v=' + PIXIJS_VERSION + '">\<\/script>');
    document.write('\<script src="game.js?v=' + VERSION + '">\<\/script>');
</script>
```

In my game.js I have:

```
PIXI.loader.add('images/textures.json?v=' + VERSION)
    .add('images/fixedsys.xml?v=' + VERSION)
    .load(setup);
```

So I just change the VERSION variable to force an update.

The problem is that textures.json is generated by TexturePacker, it contains:

```
"image": "textures.png"
```

And it's just inconvenient to add VERSION every time manually or even by a script:

```
"image": "textures.png?v=..."
```

PIXI.loader can only process json files or filenames, not objects, and I don't want to write complicated code for such a stupid case.

I also tried this to prevent caching at all:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
```

And many other variations, that either didn't work in some cases.

So my question is why caching is so annoying and if there's a simple and elegant way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Before calling `PIXI.loader.add`, add the following middleware function:

```
// Append the version to each URL to bust the browser cache.
PIXI.loader.pre((resource, next) => { resource.url += `?v=${VERSION}`; next(); });
PIXI.loader.add('images/textures.json')
    .add('images/fixedsys.xml')
    .load(setup);
```

If you need to load files that have query string arguments you should improve the middleware function to parse the URL and append our extra argument properly. But this should do for your case.